# Optimization failure in theano

Tags: python, linux, numpy, theano

I am using Fedora with the Anaconda Python environment. I have a 960m nvidia gpu, for which I have installed the required drivers and the CUDA toolkit. But when I try to run the theano tests, I end up getting the following error (in a huge error output):

```
EE.EEEERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: constant_folding
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: DimShuffle{x}(TensorConstant{2})
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I was trying to compile a simple function y, when I first saw the error. Searching for a solution led me to find that a lot of people had the same problem with the test function, but without any definite solutions. I followed the theano documentations and set the $CUDA_ROOT to my cuda root folder, but to no avail.

I'm using theano version 0.8.2 and Numpy 1.11.1, both from the conda repos. Seems like it is a GPU issue. But if it has problems, shouldn't it fallback to the CPU?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!